How to fire background activities with Awesome Notifications' SilentBackgroundActions
I use Awesome Notifications (ver 0.8.2) with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Whenever I receive a notification, I would like to be able to navigate through a certain screen, and perform actions such as reply or mark_as_seen. Awesome Notification provides a SilentAction and SilentBackgroundAction action types to fire operations in background mode: the former to silently execute whenever the app is not terminated, while the latter is used whenever it's terminated.
When I try to use SilentBackgroundAction, I get an error saying that no Dart background handler is registered, that's probably because I didn't implement a background service.
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications](22314): A new Dart background service has started (BackgroundService:24)
E/Android: [Awesome Notifications](22314): A background message could not be handled in Dart because there is no dart background handler registered. (BackgroundService:58)
W/System.err(22314): me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.exceptions.AwesomeNotificationsException: A background message could not be handled in Dart because there is no dart background handler registered.
W/System.err(22314):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.registerNewAwesomeException(ExceptionFactory.java:76)
W/System.err(22314):    at me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.services.AwesomeBackgroundService.onHandleWork(AwesomeBackgroundService.java:46)
W/System.err(22314):    at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:396)
W/System.err(22314):    at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387)
W/System.err(22314):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)

Here are some snippets of my code:
notifications.dart
class NotificationsService {
  static bool isInitialized = false;
  static ReceivedAction? initialAction;

  static Future<void> initializeNotifications() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      'resource://drawable/res_app_icon',
      languageCode: Utils.getLanguageCode(),
      debug: true,
      channelGroups: [
        NotificationChannelGroup(
          channelGroupKey: 'communication',
          channelGroupName: 'Communication',
        ),
      ],
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'chats',
          channelName: 'Chats',
          channelDescription: 'This channel is used for chats.',
          channelShowBadge: true,
          channelGroupKey: 'communication',
          defaultColor: Constants.lightColorScheme.primary,
        )
      ],
    );
    await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then(
      (isAllowed) async {
        if (!isAllowed) {
          await AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
        }
      },
    );

    await AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
      onActionReceivedMethod: NotificationsService.onActionReceivedMethod,
      onNotificationCreatedMethod: (_) async {},
      onNotificationDisplayedMethod: (_) async {},
      onDismissActionReceivedMethod: (_) async {},
    );

    await interceptInitialCallActionRequest();
  }

  static ReceivePort? receivePort;
  static Future<void> initializeIsolateReceivePort() async {
    receivePort = ReceivePort('Notification action port in main isolate');
    receivePort!.listen((serializedData) {
      print("received in background $serializedData");
      final receivedAction = ReceivedAction().fromMap(serializedData);
      handleActions(receivedAction);
    });

    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        receivePort!.sendPort,
        'notification_action_port');
  }

  static Future<void> interceptInitialCallActionRequest() async {
    initialAction = await AwesomeNotifications().getInitialNotificationAction();
    print("Initial Action ${initialAction?.payload}");
  }

  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    print('onActionReceivedMethod');
    if (receivePort != null) {
      handleActions(receivedAction);
    } else {
      print('onActionReceivedMethod was called inside a parallel dart isolate, where receivePort was never initialized.');
      SendPort? sendPort = IsolateNameServer
          .lookupPortByName('notification_action_port');

      if (sendPort != null) {
        print('Redirecting the execution to main isolate process in listening...');
        dynamic serializedData = receivedAction.toMap();
        sendPort.send(serializedData);
      }
    }
    print("payload ${receivedAction.payload}, button key ${receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed.length}");
    handleActions(receivedAction);
  }

  static void handleActions(ReceivedAction action) async {
    // my operations like mark_as_read or navigation to the right screen...
  }

  static Future<void> onBackground(RemoteMessage notification) async {
    if (!isInitialized) {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await dotenv.load(fileName: Env.file);
      await Supabase.initialize(
        url: dotenv.env[Env.supabaseUrl]!,
        anonKey: dotenv.env[Env.supabaseAnonKey]!,
      );
      isInitialized = true;
    }
    await showNotification(notification);
  }

  static Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage notification) async {
    // here i display the notification
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      // ...
      actionButtons: [
        NotificationActionButton(
          key: Notifications.reply,
          label: NotificationsEn.reply,
          autoDismissible: true,
          requireInputText: true,
          actionType: ActionType.SilentBackgroundAction,
        ),
        NotificationActionButton(
          key: Notifications.markAsRead,
          label: NotificationsEn.markAsRead,
          autoDismissible: true,
          actionType: ActionType.SilentBackgroundAction,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

main.dart
Future<void> main() async {
  // ...
  await Future.wait([
    Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform),
    NotificationsService.initializeNotifications(),
  ]);

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(NotificationsService.onBackground);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(NotificationsService.showNotification);

  runApp(
  // ...
}

Should I add a background service or does Awesome Notification already provides some background task handling?
